# How to prevent multi beginTransactions in Realmjs?

Tags: react-native, realm-js

I create a function to handle transaction, then I call it to multi places. I got crash when another transaction not yet complete when I open new transaction.

**Here my code:**

```
const RealmMakeTransaction = async (action) => {
    try {
        realm.GetInstance().beginTransaction();
        let response = await action();
        realm.GetInstance().commitTransaction();

        return response;

    } catch (e) {

        realm.GetInstance().cancelTransaction();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check if `realm` is already in transaction or not before calling `beginTransaction()` by calling `realm.GetInstance().isInTransaction`

Your code will look like :

```
const RealmMakeTransaction = async (action) => {

   //use single instance
   let realm = realm.GetInstance();

    try {
        if( realm.isInTransaction)
          realm.cancelTransaction();

        realm.beginTransaction();
        let response = await action();
        realm.commitTransaction();
        return response;

    } catch (e) {

        realm.cancelTransaction();
        realm.close();
    }
};
```